# Python Editing and Updating Excel/Csv File

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I am trying to create a program that will give me the next value in a sequence for a certain letter. For instance, A4 or B8 or C23. I believe the easiest way to do this would be to create a CSV file and reference that file in Python and update it. But I am having troubles doing it. Can I get some help? I am using Spyder/anaconda.
the program will ask what letter the user wants and it will give the next value in that letter's sequence.

Comment: Can you please expand more on the input sequence and expected output?  As (to me at least) there is not an obvious sequence in ‘A4, B8, C23’.

Comment: Show some code to get help

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library. You can use this to get and edit values in a csv or spreadsheet. You can use it like this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'yourSpreadsheet.xlsx') #select file
ws = wb.active #select worksheet
a4 = ws['A4'] #get contents of cell A4
ws['A5'] = a4 + 1 #set cell A5 to the value of cell A4+1
wb.save('resultSheet.xlsx')
```